# 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable error in fastapi

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, fastapi

I have a function where, in the end, I add a WebSocket to a background task. However, during WebSocket execution, it throws the following error:

<coroutine object FyersServiceAsync.patch_async_call at 0xffffa94f7140>
Error: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable.

```
def someFunction():
    background_tasks.add_task(access_web_socket, exist_user.id, db)


def access_web_socket(user_order_id, db):
    def modify_sl_orders(sl_order_id, trigger_price, limit_price):
        print("modify order")
```

while creating and adding websocket it keep on throwing above error as mentioned

program execution should add socket to background and it should run until it shuts down

Comment: access_web_socket function contains websocket code